# carousel notification in android

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications, carousel

Hi I need to develop a notification like carousel.

I have spent more than 2 days for implement this but not meet desired functionality.

I have tried [this](https://github.com/shaileshmamgain5/Carousel-Notification?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=5069) but not exact this which one I wanted.

Need to develop like this:-

[image]

Comment: Any findings on this ?

Comment: yes I developed but not exact this one and some issue is also there.. like multiple notifications handling. :(

Comment: Hey can you share your code for this ?

Comment: Shortly I will share my code in github, you will get this from there in a month

Comment: You can set notification again and again for new query or scroll, and for that you should set looping.

Comment: any updates on this guys?

Comment: Kindly share the code if you have developed the same.